# Maximising a window doesn't use the full screen - but I can resize windows to use all real estate

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I've just setup a third monitor in portrait mode (vertically positioned on my desk). What's strange with this is that although I can manually resize a window to use all of this screen if I maximise the window it only maximises using half of the available real estate (the top half of the monitor).

I've no idea what is causing this and Google seems to reveal a lot of resolutions for this problem in OS/X but not in Windows 7 - help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this! Keeping here for future users.

It looks like the Dual Taskbar application I was using from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/dualmonitortb/ does not support three monitors. Sorted!